# jQuery toggling visiblity of two adjacent spans

Tags: jquery

```
<span class='act_inact active'>Active</span><span class='act_inact inactive'>Inactive</span>
```

When I click .active it should become hidden and .inactive should be come visible and vice verca. As these are classes, there are many on the page.

```
$('.act_inact').click(function() {                                  
            $(this).toggle();
            $(this).closest('.act_inact').toggle(); 
        });
```

This does nothing but I don't quite know why? I'd prefer using closest() to avoid having to use next() and prev().

Comment: By the way, I recommend that you rename `act_inact` to `togglable`.

Comment: I tried using you structure and it worked. I would prefer changing the text value instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the [`closest`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest#expr) method.

The closest method will return the element's closest *parent* element that meets the condition.  For example, `$('td').closest('table')` will return the table that directly contains the `td`.  (If the table is inside another table, it will return the innermost one)

You can use the `nextAll` or `prevAll` methods along with the `:first` selector to find the closest element after or before your element, or you can use the `siblings` method to find all of the element's siblings, but I don't think there's a simple way to find the nearest sibling.

I would recommend that you nest all togglable pairs inside of separate elements, like this:

```
<div class="Togglable">
    <span class="Active">Hello!</span>
    <span class="Inactive">Goodbye!</span>
</div>
```

You can then write

```
$('.Togglable span').click(function() {                          
    $(this).parent().children().toggle(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("span.adjSpan").toggle(function() {
                $("span.active").hide();
                $("span.inactive").show();
            }, function() {
                $("span.inactive").hide();
                $("span.active").show();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .active {
            display: block;
        }

        .inactive {
            display: none;
        }

        .adjSpan { }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class='adjSpan active'>Active</span><span class='adjSpan inactive'>Inactive</span>
</body>
</html>
```